# How to call a procedure with jooq in a block statement

Tags: java, jooq, oracle18c

I wanted to play with the new jOOQ block statment feature. 
My use case is rather simpel. At least I think so ;-)

I want to execute the following SQL statement as an anonymous block

```sql
DECLARE
  v_clobdata clob;
Begin 
 select t.clob_field into v_clobdata from TEST.MY_TABLE t where t.id = 1 for update;
  DBMS_LOB.append(dest_lob => v_clobdata ,  src_lob => 'append_this');
  update TEST.MY_TABLE t set t.clob_field n = v_clobdata where t.id = 1;
END;
```

But I cannot figure out how to write the DBMS_LOB.append call with jOOQ. So far I got this:

```java
String textToAppend = "append_this";
long id = 1L;

final MY_TABLE  t = MY_TABLE .as("t");
final Variable<String> clobdata = var("v_clobDaten", SQLDataType.CLOB);
create.begin(
  declare(clobDaten),
  clobdata.set(select(t.CLOB_FIELD).from(t).where(t.ID.eq(id)).forUpdate()),
  //how  "DBMS_LOB.append(dest_lob => v_clobDaten,  src_lob => 'append_this')
  update(t).set(t.CLOB_FIELD, clobdata ).where(t.ID.eq(id))
).execute();
```

Comment: Don't you use jOOQ code generation?

Comment: Sure I do. But you cannot use the generated procedure inside a block statment.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry now I understand. I thought you have the code as stored procedure in the database and want to call that.

Comment: Did jooq generate a class for DBMS_LOB? If not you may want to include it

Comment: yes  DBMS_LOB was generated. But I cannot extract a Statment from the genrated class I can just call it and that is not what I want to do. I wan't to collect statments and then execute them together in the Database. That what the begin() Method is for. Here have a look: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/procedural-block/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to call stored functions from anonymous blocks in jOOQ's procedural API, unfortunately, we cannot model stored procedure calls in the procedural API of jOOQ 3.13 yet. The relevant feature request is this one: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9169

As a workaround, you can use the plain SQL statement API: [`DSL.statement()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#statement(org.jooq.SQL))

```
create.begin(
  declare(clobDaten),
  clobdata.set(select(t.CLOB_FIELD).from(t).where(t.ID.eq(id)).forUpdate()),
  statement("dbms_lob.append(dest_lob => {0}, src_lob => 'append_this')", clobdata),
  update(t).set(t.CLOB_FIELD, clobdata).where(t.ID.eq(id))
).execute();
```

Alternatively, in this particular case, you might be able to just use concatenation, though:

```
create.update(t)
      .set(t.CLOB_FIELD, t.CLOB_FIELD.concat("append_this"))
      .where(t.ID.eq(id))
      .execute();
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much! Also you're right concat in the update might be the better solution for my problem. But good to know that I can also call procedures in begin blocks even if currently not typed.